# Making Combinations of Elements in ArrayList [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin

I have the an ArrayList of elements which I need to get Combinations of pairs.

eg. `[A, B, C]` will be converted to `[[A, B], [A, C], [B, C]]`

I currently use the normal way of achieving this

```
for(i in 0 until arr.size-1)
    for(j in i+1 until arr.size)
        //do stuff with arr[i], arr[j]
```

and If I need combinations of more than two elements I'll probably write a recursive function to do the same. My concern is that this method is still old-school & might be not as Functional-Kotlin like

Is there a better way to achieve this & also for more number of elements in combination without going into recursion?

Comment: Why are you afraid of recursion? Kotlin compiler is able to optimize recursive functions without risk of stack overflow using keyword `tailrec`. Find details at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html

Comment: thanks, Its not that I'm afraid. I'm currently learning Kotlin, and I want to know if there's a language feature or maybe a predefined function from Collections so that I understand Kotlin and its libraries better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you can do to make it more functional is to decouple the pair production from their consumption.

The pair generator could be written with the function `sequence`:

```
fun <T> elementPairs(arr: List<T>): Sequence<Pair<T, T>> = sequence {
    for(i in 0 until arr.size-1)
        for(j in i+1 until arr.size)
            yield(arr[i] to arr[j])
}
```

Then you can use that sequence and process the pairs in different ways, e.g.

```
fun main() {
    elementPairs(listOf('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')).forEach {
        println(it)
    }

    elementPairs(listOf("apple", "desk", "arc", "density", "array"))
        .filter { (a, b) -> a.first() == b.first() }
        .forEach { println("Starting with the same letter: $it") }
}
```

You can try it here: https://pl.kotl.in/dJ9mAiATc

Comment: Great! Decoupling the logic does make it lot more elegant. Perhaps I could write this as an extension to any `Iterable` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
val arr = arrayListOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
val list= mutableListOf<Pair<String, String>>()

arr.indices.forEach() { 
    i -> arr.indices.minus(0..i).forEach() { 
    j -> list.add(arr[i] to arr[j]) }
}
println(list)
```

Output

```
[(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers above are really verbose for Kotlin standards. This can be solved using flatmap which much more succinct IMO:

```
fun main() {
    val letters = "ABC".toList();
    val pairs = letters
        .flatMap {first -> letters
        .filter{second -> !first.equals(second)} // if you want to exclude "identity" pairs
        .map{second->first to second }};
    println(pairs)
}
```

Comment: These repeats all the combinations though. For example this returns "A,C" and "C,A" - the OP only wants one of those,

Answer (score 1):

So the accepted answer creates pairs.  I created an object that works on any length combinations up to the the items.size -1

```
class CombinationGenerator<T>(private val items: List<T>, choose: Int = 1) : Iterator<List<T>>, Iterable<List<T>> {
    private val indices = Array(choose) { it }
    private var first = true

    init {
        if (items.isEmpty() || choose > items.size || choose < 1)
            error("list must have more than 'choose' items and 'choose' min is 1")
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = indices.filterIndexed { index, it ->
        when (index) {
            indices.lastIndex -> items.lastIndex > it
            else -> indices[index + 1] - 1 > it
        }
    }.any()

    override fun next(): List<T> {
        if (!hasNext()) error("AINT NO MORE WHA HAPPEN")
        if (!first) {
            incrementAndCarry()
        } else
            first = false
        return List(indices.size) { items[indices[it]] }
    }

    private fun incrementAndCarry() {
        var carry = false
        var place = indices.lastIndex
        do {
            carry = if ((place == indices.lastIndex && indices[place] < items.lastIndex)
                    || (place != indices.lastIndex && indices[place] < indices[place + 1] - 1)) {
                indices[place]++
                (place + 1..indices.lastIndex).forEachIndexed { index, i ->
                    indices[i] = indices[place] + index + 1
                }
                false
            } else
                true
            place--
        } while (carry && place > -1)
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<List<T>> = this
}

fun main() {
    val combGen = CombinationGenerator(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4), 3)
    combGen.map { println(it.joinToString()) }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4) //test array

arr.indices.forEach() {
    i -> arr.indices.minus(0..i).forEach() {
    j -> println("${arr[i]} ${arr[j]}") } }
```

Output

```
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```